# Flexbox struggles

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm struggling to create a fixed header and footer using flexbox.
Header and footer actually consists just of an element on each side. I'd like to make the elements fixed and the content in the middle scrollable. I also don't get it how to position my footer at the bottom of the viewport.

[image]

Nothing crazy actually but I don't understand what I am doing wrong?

```css
body {
  font-family: DejaVu Sans Mono;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

nav a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.intro-container {
  display: flex;
}

.intro-text {
  font-size: 42px;
  line-height: 52px;
}

.placeholder {
  width: 500px;
  height: 800px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 65vw;
  top: 85vh;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}



@media screen and (min-width: 300px) {

  .top ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .bottom ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    top: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  nav {
  }


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>


<nav class="top">
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="index.html"> text1 </a> </li>
    <li> <a href=""> text2 </a> </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="intro-container">
  <h1 class="intro-text">
    Lorem Ipsum 
  </h1>
</div>

<nav class="bottom">
  <ul>
    <li> <a href=""> text3 </a> </li>
    <li> <a href=""> text4 </a> </li>
  </ul>
</nav>



  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flex properties to pin the anchors to all four corners.

Then use `overflow: auto` to make the content scrollable.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;  /* pin header and footer to top and bottom edges */
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;  /* pin anchors to left and right edges */
}

nav a {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.intro-container {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<nav class="top">
  <a href="index.html"> text1 </a>
  <a href=""> text2 </a>
</nav>

<div class="intro-container">
  <h1 class="intro-text">
    Lorem Ipsum
  </h1>
  <p>I'm struggling to create a fixed header and footer using flexbox. Header and footer actually consists just of an element on each side. I'd like to make the elements fixed and the content in the middle scrollable. I also don't get it how to position
    my footer at the bottom of the viewport.</p>
  <p>I'm struggling to create a fixed header and footer using flexbox. Header and footer actually consists just of an element on each side. I'd like to make the elements fixed and the content in the middle scrollable. I also don't get it how to position
    my footer at the bottom of the viewport.</p>
  <p>I'm struggling to create a fixed header and footer using flexbox. Header and footer actually consists just of an element on each side. I'd like to make the elements fixed and the content in the middle scrollable. I also don't get it how to position
    my footer at the bottom of the viewport.</p>
  <p>I'm struggling to create a fixed header and footer using flexbox. Header and footer actually consists just of an element on each side. I'd like to make the elements fixed and the content in the middle scrollable. I also don't get it how to position
    my footer at the bottom of the viewport.</p>
  <p>I'm struggling to create a fixed header and footer using flexbox. Header and footer actually consists just of an element on each side. I'd like to make the elements fixed and the content in the middle scrollable. I also don't get it how to position
    my footer at the bottom of the viewport.</p>
  <p>I'm struggling to create a fixed header and footer using flexbox. Header and footer actually consists just of an element on each side. I'd like to make the elements fixed and the content in the middle scrollable. I also don't get it how to position
    my footer at the bottom of the viewport.</p>
  <p>I'm struggling to create a fixed header and footer using flexbox. Header and footer actually consists just of an element on each side. I'd like to make the elements fixed and the content in the middle scrollable. I also don't get it how to position
    my footer at the bottom of the viewport.</p>
  <p>I'm struggling to create a fixed header and footer using flexbox. Header and footer actually consists just of an element on each side. I'd like to make the elements fixed and the content in the middle scrollable. I also don't get it how to position
    my footer at the bottom of the viewport.</p>
  <p>I'm struggling to create a fixed header and footer using flexbox. Header and footer actually consists just of an element on each side. I'd like to make the elements fixed and the content in the middle scrollable. I also don't get it how to position
    my footer at the bottom of the viewport.</p>
</div>

<nav class="bottom">
  <a href=""> text3 </a>
  <a href=""> text4 </a>
</nav>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fn5cqby5/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to create a layout with a left, middle and right column using flex (`.container` in the snippet), and use flex to layout the `ul` in the left and right column.

I added a fixed height on the `div.container` to demonstrate. In your real use you will need to set `body` and `div.container` to 100%. The snippet display here causes issues demonstrating that. I also added borders to show the layout of the main columns.

```css
body {
  font-family: DejaVu Sans Mono;
}

div.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
}
div.container > * {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
nav {
  display: flex;
}
nav a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.intro-container {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.intro-text {
  font-size: 42px;
  line-height: 52px;
}

.placeholder {
  width: 500px;
  height: 800px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 65vw;
  top: 85vh;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>

<div class="container">
<nav class="left">
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="index.html"> text1 </a> </li>
    <li> <a href=""> text3 </a> </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="intro-container">
  <h1 class="intro-text">
    Lorem Ipsum 
  </h1>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>

<nav class="right">
  <ul>
    <li> <a href=""> text2 </a> </li>
    <li> <a href=""> text4 </a> </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```